# loop in nested loop inside json response swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, xcode

I have this JSON respone:

```
{
    "success": false,
    "message": {
       "gender": [
           "The gender field is required."
       ],
       "sms_token": [
           "The sms token field is required."
       ]
   }
}
```

note that the message object could have more than two elements...

and I'm trying to get the array inside message object... I have tried this:

```
guard let messages = receivedTodo["message"] as? String, let message = receivedTodo["sms_token"] as? String else {
                    print("Could not get messages from JSON")
                    return
                }
                print("The error is:" + message)
            }
```

but this didn't work and i will always get "could not get messages from JSON"...

I want to loop and get all of the elements inside message object and print them out.. how to archive this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
guard let messages = receivedTodo["message"] as? [String:Any],let tokens = messages["sms_token"] as? [String], let genders = messages["gender"] as? [String] else {  
    return
} 
for token in tokens {
      print(token)
}
for gender in genders {
      print(gender)
}
```

Comment: He clearly said that wrong. From the structure it is clear that it is a dictionary.

Comment: He said: note that the message object could have more than two elements...

Comment: Yes, as in key values, not an array.

Comment: Why are you keeping Any as the value ? In the current JSON, both values are String.

Comment: Can you see `message` doesn't have the string value ??

Comment: I see. Upvoting.

Comment: i got this error for tokens: variable declared in guard condition is not usable in its body

Comment: now it's working, but how can i add another messages? for example gender, name, ...?

Comment: now it will display only the message for sms
_token

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Please **read** the JSON, it's pretty easy, there are only two different collection types, array (`[]`) and dictionary (`{}`).

- The value for key `message` is a dictionary.
- The value for key  `sms_token` is an array of `String`.

  ```
  guard let messages = receivedTodo["message"] as? [String:Any], 
        let message = messages["sms_token"] as? [String],
        !message.isEmpty else {
              print("Could not get messages from JSON")
              return
          }
          print("The error is:" + message.joined(separator:", "))
      }
  ```

  or even

  ```
  ...
  guard let messages = receivedTodo["message"] as? [String:[String]],
      let message = messages["sms_token"], !message.isEmpty else { ...
  ```

To get all error messages – regardless of the dictionary keys – write

```
guard let messages = receivedTodo["message"] as? [String:[String]] else {
        print("Could not get messages from JSON")
        return
}
for (key, value) in messages {
    print("The \(key) error is: " + value.joined(separator:", "))
}
```

Comment: Now its working, but how about the other messages? it could have another error messages for example name, gender,... how to add them all?

Comment: I updated the answer to print all error messages regardless of the dictionary keys.

Comment: It's working perfectly now! Thank you so much for the help!